# How to Logoff user when a user logsIn some where else

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the functionality with which , when a user is loggedIn at one place and when he try to login to some where else , He should automatically be LoggedOut from the previous place .

Like in GMAIL..

If some one can give me the concept , As i think I need to save the user LoggedIn Status in Db,As sessions doesnt looks to be heplful. But then I dont understand how we update user status in DB ,if there is no activity for lets say 5 minutes (how will i capture the inactivity and updating in db).

If some one can please guide, I am struggling on this for hours now .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When user login add the user session with id to a hashmap. When the same user logins again check for entry in the HashMap and if available invalidate the session and create new session for the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Security, it provides this functionality out of the box.
Otherwise:

Create a `java.util.Map` (A ConcurrentMap is prefered, so manipulating it concurrently won't corrupt it), and stores it in application scope (ServletContext).

Now, you shall store each user and a reference to its session upon login in the map, and if a user logins again, just fetch previous session object and invalidate it.

Now implement an instance of `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`, and in `void sessionDestroyed(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent);` method, remove the specified session from the Map. (This listener is invoked on session invalidation, whether it is done automatically by container or if you do it programmatically). just register this listener in `web.xml` and everything is done.

p.s. I know that it will be some-how harder, if you are deploying your application on a cluster of web-containers, but when you have just one server, that's ok.
p.s. I don't recommend storing session information in DB.